# asp.net metaresource key failed to take value on resx file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, localization, resx

I am currently building a project with localization. I work on some .aspx files and i "localize" all the strings in it. Firstly i go to .aspx file on Design View. Then Tools->Generate Local Resource. This builds a .resx file with most of the strings and their values automatically.

When i find a string like this:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                Κατάσταση:
```

Κατάσταση==Situation on Greek. I mark "Κατάσταση" and i use resharper (Alt+enter => MoveHtmlToResource) and it generates a row on the .resx file with value "Κατάσταση" and the name that i typed.

My problem is on something like that:

```
<asp:Button ID="SituationButton" runat="server" CommandName="Situation" Text="Κατάσταση" />
```

There is no metaresource key attribute and the resharper does nothing here. When i try to type manually the metaresourcekey like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="SituationButton" runat="server" CommandName="Situation" Text="Κατάσταση" meta:resourcekey="Situation"/>
```

it creates a new row on the .resx file with name="Situation" and the value="Situation". The value should be "Κατάσταση".

The purpose of this is to built a multiple language web site.
Any ideas? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="SituationButton" runat="server" CommandName="Situation" Text="Κατάσταση" meta:resourcekey="Situation"/>
```

Then you change manually the .resx file value from "Situation" to "Κατάσταση"